# Why Rust enforces 'static lifetime even I have specified one? Can I override it?

Tags: rust, callback, closures, lifetime

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong. I'm writing a `Callback` structure for indirectly calling a closure, this code will be used with a C library.

I've tried to explicit declaring lifetime for a `Callback` class, but Rust enforces me the `'static` lifetime, where I know it is not static. My code looks like this:

```rust
use std::ffi::c_void;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Callback<'h> {
    f: Box<dyn FnMut()>,
    r: *const c_void,
    _lifetime: PhantomData<&'h ()>
}

impl<'h> Callback<'h> {
    fn new<F>(handler: F) -> Self where F: FnMut() + Send + 'h {
        let f = Box::new(handler);
        let r = f.as_ref() as *const dyn FnMut() as *const c_void;
        Callback::<'h> { f, r, _lifetime: PhantomData }
    }
}
```

The compiler error is following:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `F` may not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:14:26
   |
14 |         Callback::<'h> { f, r, _lifetime: PhantomData }
   |                          ^ ...so that the type `F` will meet its required lifetime bounds
   |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...
   |
11 |     fn new<F>(handler: F) -> Self where F: FnMut() + Send + 'h + 'static {
   |                                                                +++++++++
```

If I use the suggested `'static` lifetime, then the closure has to be static which it's not my intention.

How to force Rust to *trust* my lifetime? Is there any workaround? Or, is there any other ways to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing `Box<dyn Trait>` in a struct field will have a default `'static` constraint on the trait object. You can relax this by annotating it with `'h` instead:

```
struct Callback<'h> {
    f: Box<dyn FnMut() + 'h>, // <------------
    r: *const c_void,
    _lifetime: PhantomData<&'h ()>
}
```

<sup>With that change you probably don't need `_lifetime` anymore.</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that the generic type also needs the timeline! This works perfectly!

Comment: Can you clarify please? How the struct can have lifetimes if there is no refferences in it?

Comment: @user3070377 trait objects can represent any type, which means they can represent structs that *do* have references. The syntax above is used to denote that the trait object is allowed to have references as long as they live for `'h`.